# Webdriver can't control popups

Tags: java, popup, selenium-webdriver, popupwindow

After sending click with findElement, I Cant go on to the next action of handling the popup  until popup closed (manually), since current window is not in control, therefore webdriver waits forever.

Im trying to do the following:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(salesforceButtons.CUSTOM_OBJECT_DELETE.getValue())).click();
Set<String> windowId = driver.getWindowHandles();    // get  window id of current window
Iterator<String> itererator = windowId.iterator();   
String mainWinID = itererator.next()
String  newAdwinID = itererator.next();
driver.switchTo().window(newAdwinID);
```

But it stuck after the click.

Comment: it the popup window a system window? like a file chooser? if so, you can't control it in selenium. please explain in more detail and show the html.

Comment: Its a javascript window

Comment: so it is part of the original page DOM? Then you should be able to control it and you don't need to do the window handle thing you do.

Comment: Its not part of the original page DOM.

Comment: sorry. without more insight into the html of the pages I can't help. How can you be sure the ```newAdwinID``` is the correct window?

Comment: The section after the click is not my problem since I dont get there at all, because as I said stuck at the click action.

Comment: Bu the way, how can I attach the html?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use the following (presuming by pop-up you mean a browser alert window):

```
Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
alert.accept()
```

I may be wrong with this, and it may be that you do need to iterate through the windows, however, the code you've stated isn't doing that, it is simply changing the window focus to the one defined by the second result in the driver.getWindowHandles() set. Might I suggest the following if it's not just a simple alert:

```
String startWinId = driver.getWindowHandle(); // caches the current window id    
driver.findElement(By.xpath(salesforceButtons.CUSTOM_OBJECT_DELETE.getValue())).click();
Set<String> windowId = driver.getWindowHandles(); // actually gets all available windows ids
Iterator<String> iterator = windowId.iterator();

// Iterates through each active window and does stuff within that window.
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    driver.switchTo().window(iterator.next());
    <insert code to run against each window here>
}   

// Switches back to the original window to carry on with executing tests
driver.switchTo().window(startWinId);
```